# Android Java How do ı fill parent in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add 3 LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout with wrap_content width length, but ı didnt find any way to fill the parent.
RelativeLayout doesnt support weigth, so ı need an alternative for this.
[A preview of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87VvE.png)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gameModeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mode1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mode2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMode1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntutitling"
            android:text="Üretici" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mode2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMode2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/consolaz"
            android:text="İşleyici" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mode3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mode2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMode3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/consolaz"
            android:text="Satıcı" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However ı can use also LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout but maybe there is an other solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraint layout rather than using these relative or linear layout. Constraint layout have so much power and comparatively very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As Umer suggested the best option would be to use constraint layout, however if you want to use linear and relative layout a possible solution could be

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gameModeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/mode1"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/mode2"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/mode3"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</ReativeLayout>
```